# How to add existing heroku dataclips to local postgres development database?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

What is a neat way to recreate heroku dataclips on my local machine so that I have immediate access to the same useful queries locally which I do on an instance of my app on heroku?

I'm referring to the ability to query the state of the local database one is working with during application development, i.e. testing data, if you like (though of course after I `pg:pull` it's simply a copy of production data for testing purposes).

I have found I have come to rely on the views the dataclips give me into production data, which then assists in the courage to not allow primitive readability of bare tables to be a significant design consideration when adding to or adjusting my database schema. That means I can pursue more normalisation with confidence which can be wonderfully freeing.

So, I just realised this morning that this could be really quite useful, so, lets consider it two steps:

1. A high level overview of the concepts involved.
2. Details of how to do it, with some examples.

So to start with, do heroku dataclips correspond directly (postgres) database views?

Answer (score 1):

Heroku Dataclips does nothing more than execute a given query and display/visualize the resulting data set. Additionally, dataclips are only able to query against Heroku Postgres databases. Simply put, there's no way to target a local database with the heroku dataclip tooling.

You could potentially create a Heroku Postgres database with the express purpose to model the state of your local development database and use that. For instance, every time you'd like to run a dataclip against your local instance you'd push the data up to this purposed database and then execute the dataclip against that database. It's an extra step but if you need to use Dataclips it's likely the only reasonable way to do it for the purposes you've expressed here.

Comment: Thanks. I think creating some views in the database may be the answer to my use case and is what I'll do next. That means the dataclips can be very short sql queries against the views, which I can then also of course run on the local instance without having to type a whole bunch of common table expressions as I would have to now if I wanted actual dataclip equivalent on my local instance. It's really a question of convenience that I'm seeking to address here.

Comment: Of course, putting the dataclip query into a file `dataclip.sql` and running `psql -d databasename -f dataclip.sql` locally looks like another way, will explore that in terms of convenience too. I think I'm trying to learn best use of views here at the same time though, sorry...